# Sending Callbacks/Functions from native to javascript

Tags: javascript, android, swift, react-native

Is it possible to return a Callback/function or a NativeModule instance back to the calling javascript via a Promise or Callback in Android and Swift?

What I'd like to happen is:

1. JS calls NativeModule method with either Promise or Callback arguments
2. The NativeModule (Android or Swift) then returns a handle such as a Callback or another NativeModule back to the JS. This will be used to call a function that may interrupt an async execution occurring in the native code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible currently, but have submitted a feature enhancement request.